# Is “double dot” (“··”) notation used for a double radical?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, notation, radicals

I wondered if this was a typo in the notes given to me. I haven’t come across notation like this before:

> **Branching** — steps in which number of radicals increases (can lead
> to explosion)
>
> $$\ce{H^. + O2 -> OH^. + O^{..}}$$

Comment: Alone, the oxygen atom has always two separated uncoupled electrons. It never lasts a long time like this, but It has two doublets and two independent electrons in the outer shell. This makes a total of $6$ electrons. On the other hand, the molecule $\ce{O2}$ is a double radical, with one free electron on either Oxygen atoms..

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you so much for this

Comment: It's call diradical or biradical, just saying ;)

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** The double dot notation is reserved for lone pairs.
Diradicals are depicted either with the appropriately placed superscripted dots within a structural formula (e.g. $\ce{^.O-O^.}),$ or superscripted multiplier–dot pair (e.g. $\ce{O2^{2.}}).$
The recommended notation for monooxygen 1,1-diradical is $\ce{O^{2.}}.$

---

First, let's sort out terminology.
The recommended name for “double radical” is [*diradical*](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/D01765) [[1, p. 1333](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307)]:

> **diradicals:**
> Molecular species having two unpaired electrons, in which at least two different electronic states with different multiplicities [electron-paired (singlet state) or electron-unpaired (triplet state)] can be identified.
> *E.g.* $\ce{H2C^.-CH2C^.H2}$ propane-1,3-diyl (trimethylene). See *biradicals*.

The term [*biradical*](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/B00671), although being synonymous, is less preferable [[1, p. 1322](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307)]:

> **biradicals:**
> Although this term has been recommended in the past for *diradicals*, specialists working in the field prefer the latter term.

So, we are dealing with a diradical.
You are probably familiar with a low-energy oxygen 1,2-diradical commonly depicted as $\ce{^.O-O^.}.$
What if we are dealing with a 1,1-diradical?
Note that two dots next to each other signify a *lone pair* (remember water $(\ce{H-\overset{\Large .\!\!.}{\underset{\Large .\!\!.}{O}}-H})$ or ammonia $(\ce{:\!\!NH3})?)$ and when being used for the depiction of diradicals will inevitably cause confusion.

This seeming contradiction is resolved if you follow guidelines provided in section *IR-4.6.2 Formulae of radical* from [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (Red Book)*](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/redbook/) (emphasis mine) [2, p. 66]:

> A radical is an atom or molecule with one or more unpaired electrons.
> It may have positive, negative or zero charge.
> An unpaired electron may be indicated in a formula by a superscript dot.
> The dot is placed as a right upper index to the chemical symbol, so as not to interfere with indications of mass number, atomic number or composition.
> **In the case of diradicals, *etc.*, the superscript dot is preceded by the appropriate superscript multiplier.**
> The radical dot with its multiplier, if any, precedes any charge.
> To avoid confusion, the multiplier and the radical dot can be placed within parentheses.
>
> […]
>
> *Examples:*
>
> […]
>
> 4. $\ce{O2^{2.}}$
>
> […]
>
> 8. $\ce{NO^{(2.)-}}$
> 9. $\ce{N2^{(2.)2+}}$

Here you can also find nomenclature for this species [2, p. 319]:

> $\ce{O^{2.}},$ oxidanylidene, monooxygen(2•)

Following these recommendations, I would suggest to rewrite your scheme as follows:

$$\ce{H^. + O2 -> HO^. + O^{2.}}$$

#### References

1. Moss, G. P.; Smith, P. A. S.; Tavernier, D. Glossary of Class Names of Organic Compounds and Reactivity Intermediates Based on Structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **1995**, 67 (8–9), 1307–1375. DOI: [10.1351/pac199567081307](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307).
2. IUPAC. *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, IUPAC Recommendations 2005* (the “Red Book”), 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; RSC Publishing: Cambridge, UK, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2.